# Multiple values in one cell from select query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm trying to do a select query to show values from two tables. Going to use "Customers" and "Orders at an example. In customers table it just has CustomerID (primary key) and CustomerName (no duplicates). The Orders table shows CustomerName (foreign key) and Order#.

When a customer has multiple orders in the Order table it shows like this

```
Jon - Order1
Jon - Order2
Luke - Order1
Luke - ORder2
Luke - Order3
Mark - Order1
```

How can I get the select query to show it like this

```
Jon - Order1, Order2
Luke - Order1, Order2, Order3
Mark - Order1
```

It doesn't have to be separated by commas. A stack field will work too. My end goal is to have an "Orders form" that lists each customer with all of their orders in a single "order" field in the form/

Example of the form will be a textbox with the CustomerName and another textbox to list every Order

Current SQL

```
SELECT tblCustomers.CustomerName, tblOrders.Order#
From tblCustomers INNER JOIN tblOrders ON tblCustomers.CustomerName = tblOrders.CustomerName
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MS Access doesn't natively offer this functionality, therefore, you'll need to use a VBA function similar to Allen Browne's [ConcatRelated](http://allenbrowne.com/func-concat.html) function.

Applied to your example, you could use this function in the following manner:

```
select
    t.customername, 
    ConcatRelated("[order#]", "tblorders", "customername = '" & t.customername & "'") 
from
    tblcustomers t
```

However, I would advise against this representation of data in favour of using a subform.

---

Aside, it's really odd that your tables are linked on the Customer **Name** as opposed to the **ID**.

Comment: I was just using that as an example to try to make it simple. In my actual tables I don't have a "CustomerID" value in the "Orders" table. The CustomerID is an automated number in the Customers table. I'm open to doing it differently if there's a better way. I'm basically teaching myself Access right now.



Also, a subform would be fine too. I'll look into that. When using a subform, could I still show multiple values in one box? So when a customer named Luke has two orders and it shows up as two rows in a table. I could have those two orders show up in one textbox on Luke's order form?

Comment: Just read through the ConcatRelated function you posted. Looks like it'll do what I'm trying to accomplish. If using a subform is a better way to do this. I'd rather do that though. Not sure how I can accomplish it though. Not sure if this is possible but another way would be instead of putting the order numbers into one textbox. I could have the form create however many textboxes needed and put the order numbers into there. So in the form, under order numbers, it'll have two textboxes if there are two orders associated with that customer

Comment: A subform with display set to datasheet view and Master/Child fields linked via the customer ID will produce precisely the results that you are looking to obtain, without the need for VBA - there are *many* tutorials online on the subject of creating a subform, and displaying a list of orders for a given customer is a very typical example (it is likely even included in the Northwind sample database provided freely with MS Access). If you get stuck creating your subform, it would be better to create a new question rather than replying to the comments here.